# Monkeyrunner is using python 2.x instead of 3.x

Tags: python, android, testing, monkeyrunner

I am using monkeyrunner for my test. but the problem is that it is using python 2 instead of version 3. I've installed python3 only on my system. I do not know where is the python 2! is it on the test phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monkey runner is using the embedded python 2.x implementation and there is no way to change it unless its developers update it.

I had to use `txt` file instead of `JSON` to port my code to python 2.x .